# Optimization failing after very few iterations for nonlinear constraints calculated in a blackbox wrapped in an explicit component

Tags: openmdao

I have a blackbox solver which is wrapped as explicit component and the objective function and constraints are calculated in the blackbox solver and output. These are taken to a constraint components that has an equality constraint defined such that at any iteration, these constraints are satisifed. I am using finite difference to approximate the partial derivatives. However, I get this SLSQP error **"Positive directional derivative for linesearch"**. From S.O., I understand that this error translates - optimizer could not find a direction to move to and also couldn't verify if the results are minimum.  I found that for some iterations derivative is 'None' and it was 'None' at least a few times before it threw this error. Is it because the constraints are calculated in the black box solver? or is it because 'fd' for approximation is not working for non linear constraints? or both? A problem summary is attached for reference.
[image][image]

```html
from PowerHarvest import *
from HydroDynamics import *
from SatelliteComms import *
from Propulsion import *
from Constraints import *
from SystemCost import *



class MDA(Group):
    """Multidisciplinary Analysis Group"""

    def __init__(self,  derivative_method='fd', **kwargs):
        super(MDA, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.derivative_method = 'fd'
     


    def setup(self):

        cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle',Group(), promotes = ["*"]) 

        cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems = True)
        cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['atol'] = 1e-6
        cycle.add_subsystem('Hydro', Hydro(),promotes = ["*"]) #This is a blackbox explicit component!
        cycle.add_subsystem('Propulsion_system', Propulsion(),promotes = ["*"])
        cycle.add_subsystem('PowerHarvest_system',PowerHarvest(),promotes = ["*"])
        cycle.add_subsystem("SatelitteComs_system", SatelitteComs(),promotes = ["*"])

        
        cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['atol'] = 1.0e-5
        cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['maxiter'] = 500
        cycle.nonlinear_solver.options['iprint'] = 2

        #Add constraint on the each subsytem if possible 
        #cycle.add_constraint('',om.ex)
       
       
        self.add_subsystem('PowerConstraints_system', PowerConstraints(), promotes=["*"])
        self.add_subsystem('BodyConstraints_system', BodyConstraint(),promotes = ["*"])
       
        self.add_subsystem('SystemCost_system',SystemCost(), promotes = ['*'])

      
        self.add_constraint('A_PV', upper = 100, units = 'm**2')
        #these constraints are output of the blackbox solver!
        self.add_constraint('AreaCon', upper = 0)
        self.add_constraint('massCon',equals = 0)
        self.add_constraint('P_Load', upper = 0) # Solar generates just enough for everything no storing!
        self.add_constraint('DraughtCon', lower = 0.5   )
        self.add_constraint('GMCon', lower = 0.01) #should be positive
        #self.add_constraint('theta', upper = 0.14, lower = 0.1)
        self.add_constraint('Amplitude_Con',upper = -0.1) #amplitude differenc
```

Added. Run script

```html
import openmdao.api as om
from geom_utils import *
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, ExplicitComponent,ImplicitComponent, IndepVarComp, ExecComp,\
    NonlinearBlockGS, ScipyOptimizeDriver,NewtonSolver,DirectSolver,ScipyKrylov
import os
import numpy as np
from types import FunctionType
from geom_utils import *
from capytaine.meshes.meshes import Mesh
from pprint import pprint

from PowerHarvest import *
from HydroDynamics import *
from SatelliteComms import *
from Propulsion import *
from Constraints import *
from SystemCost import *
from PEARLMDA import *



if __name__ == '__main__':
    prob = Problem()
    model = prob.model = MDA()

    prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver(optimizer = 'SLSQP')
    # prob.model.nonlinear_solver = om.NonlinearBlockGS()
    #prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'COBYLA'
    prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-5


    prob.model.add_design_var('Df', lower= 6.0, upper=20.0, units = "m")
    prob.model.add_design_var('tf', lower=1.0, upper=4.0, units = "m")
    #prob.model.add_design_var('submergence', upper = -0.9)
    prob.model.add_design_var('Vs', lower=1, upper=2, units = "m/s") #make sure the lower, upper are according to their units.
    prob.model.add_design_var('ld', lower = 3, upper = 7, units = 'm' )

   
    prob.model.add_objective('cost_per_byte' ) 

   
    newton = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=True)
    newton.linesearch = om.BoundsEnforceLS()
    prob.model.nonlinear_solver = newton
    prob.model.linear_solver = om.DirectSolver()

    # sqlite file to record the intermediate calculations and derivatives
    r = om.SqliteRecorder("pearl_computations.sql")
    prob.add_recorder(r)
    prob.driver.add_recorder(r)
    prob.driver.recording_options["record_derivatives"] = True
    # Attach recorder to a subsystem
    model.nonlinear_solver.add_recorder(r)

    model.add_recorder(r)
    prob.driver.recording_options["includes"] = ["*"]

# Attach recorder to a solver
    model.nonlinear_solver.add_recorder(r)
    prob.setup()
    prob.set_solver_print(level=2)

# For gradients across the model this will do the finite difference method
    prob.model.approx_totals(method="fd", step=0.1, form="forward", step_calc="abs")   
    prob.run_model()
    prob.run_driver()
    prob.record("final_state")
    print('minimum objective found at')
    print(prob['cost_per_byte'][0])
    print(prob['A_PV'])
    print(f"tf: {prob['tf'][0]}")

    results = dict()
    results['tf'] = prob['tf'][0]
    results['Df'] = prob['Df'][0]
    results['ld'] = prob['ld'][0]
    results['mass'] = prob['Payloadmass'][0]
    results['DraughCon'] = prob['DraughtCon'][0]
    results['AmplitudeCon'] = prob['AmplitudeCon'][0]

    print(results)
```

Scaling report
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed question! Can you please also share your run script, like where you call `run_driver`? I want to see how you're setting up and calling the problem. Additionally, do you mean to use FD to approximate the total derivatives, like this? https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_totals.html If so, you may need additional logic at the run script level if you don't have it already.

Comment: Hi @JohnJasa thanks for the quick reply! I have added the run script as well.

Comment: Great, thanks for this info! At first glance, I'd say your FD step size is quite large, especially given your design variable bounds. Have you performed a step size study to determine the best FD step size? If you try 1.e-6, what happens? See Tip 6.2 in Chap. 6 of this book for more info: http://flowlab.groups.et.byu.net/mdobook.pdf

Comment: Hi, I tried with 1e-6 but the problem still persists. The optimization does not converge. There's a lot of values calculated in the blackbox solver that are later used in constraint functions. So when openmdao runs the compute function of the component does it calculates all the output and caches it or runs each time one of these output/constraints values are required. I am thinking because I have many outputs and the max iteration is 500 but this is actually doing num of output * 500 iterations hence taking too long. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: OpenMDAO will just run the compute method and cache the results for later. Examining your code, you have a linear solver at the run script level but not at the MDA level. The Newton nonlinear solver requires accurate derivatives to converge. You might try adding a linear solver at the MDA level to help solve this system.